# Write command terminal

Tags: shell

Someone created some sort of script to continually write to my screen using the shell command write.  If I logout and then log back in it does not stop.  Is there any way to stop this once it has started?

Answer (score 1):

To stop other users from writing to your terminal, you can issue the command:

```
mesg n
```

If the write command is coming from your own account, it's likely being run on profile load. Your best bet is to navigate to your `~/.profile` file or equivalent and try to find the alias or malicious script.

Best of luck.